# How do I efficiently access functions by index in Julia?

Tags: function, optimization, julia, global

I havea set of functions that I want to use on some data. Currently, I am storing these functions in a global array to be able to index them.

```
const global _rot01(x)::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64} = ( x[1],  x[2],  x[3])
const global _rot02(x)::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64} = ( x[2],  x[3],  x[1])
...
const global _rot24(x)::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64} = (-x[1], -x[3], -x[2])

const global Rotations = [
    _rot01,
    ...
    _rot24
]
```

However, I wish to optimize this, as I have heard that global values should be avoided. A switch statement would allow me to efficiently select the right function, but these are not available. Is this vector of functions the only way to do this? How efficient is this? Also, should I replace the functions with 'real' function definitions?

Comment: It seems like there could be a systematic way to generate these functions (enumerating all rotations?) instead of writing them out. That could actually be more elegant. Something like `@generated function rot(x, ::Val{N})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not need to write:

```
const global _rot01(x)::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64} = ( x[1],  x[2],  x[3])
```

It is enough to define functions like this:

```
_rot01(x)::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64} = ( x[1],  x[2],  x[3])
```

Functions are const by default. And what you write are real function definitions. Also you do not need to write `::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}` (unless you know you need to to force conversion of data), it is enough to just write:

```
_rot01(x) = ( x[1],  x[2],  x[3])
```

Unless `x` is some strange data structure (e.g. vector of `Any`) Julia will do detection of return type of the function automatically.

Second in:

```
const global Rotations = [
    _rot01,
    ...
    _rot24
]
```

you do not need to write `global` (I understand you are defining `Rotations` in global scope).

Instead I think a nice thing to write would be:

```
const global Rotations = (; _rot01, ... _rot24)
```

This defines you a `Rotations` as a named tuple, you can then access it as:

```
Rotations[1]
```

or

```
Rotations._rot01
```

to get the first function and it will be efficient.

If you do not like it then doing a tuple:

```
const global Rotations = (_rot01, ... _rot24)
```

is also OK (but you then only have access by index not by name).

Now why defining:

```
const Rotations = [
    _rot01,
    ...
    _rot24
]
```

is bad. The reason is that then the element type of this vector will be `Function` which means that your code will not be type stable as `Function` is an abstract type (as opposed to `Tuple` or `NamedTuple` that specialize their field types). And type unable code leads to performance degradation.

Finally,

You only need to define `Rotations` as `const` if you want to access it from global scope. But if you want to pass it to functions it is fully OK to just define it as a normal variable and pass as a function parameter and things will be fast.

I know that I touched a lot of things in the answer. If something requires further clarification please comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I just have a small question. You said that this is enough _rot01(x) = ( x[1],  x[2],  x[3]). Shouldn't I at least give the type of the argument e.g. _rot01(x::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}) = ( x[1],  x[2],  x[3])?

Comment: No, you do not need to do this. Julia will automatically detect it. Adding ` _rot01(x::Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}) = ( x[1], x[2], x[3])` will only have an effect that if you try to pass to `_rot01` something else than such a tuple you will get an error. So this would be a "safety measure"; which is of course sensible for production purposes, but it requires more code, so people usually do not want to write such code :), and that is why it is not required (just like in e.g. Python). It would not have an impact on performance.